# JSPDF - Only a part of the page

Tags: jquery, jspdf

I'm trying to export the content of a DIV in a PDF using the library jsPDF .

The problem is that when i try to export the content of the div, what I see in the pdf is only a part of the real content of the div and there isn't all the document I want to export.

Here is the code :

```
// Javascript
function pdf() {
        var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'in', 'letter');
        var specialElementHandlers = {
            '#ricercaChat': function (element, renderer) {
                return true;
            }
        };
        doc.fromHTML($("#ricercaChat").html(), 15, 15, {
                'width':170,
                'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        });
        doc.save('role.pdf');
    }

//HTML
<a href="#" onclick="pdf()"><img src="immagini/pdf1.png"></a>
<div id="ricercaChat" width="100%">  
...( html loaded with jQuery.load that is another page )</div>
```

I've tried to modify the function in :

```
var htmlall = document.getElementById('ricercaChat').innerHTML; // there is ALL the html content
doc.fromHTML(htmlall, 15, 15, { ...
```

Doing in this mode, the pdf is completely blank.

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with this block of code:

```
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#ricercaChat': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};
```

What it does is, it tells jsPDF to ignore the content in "**#ricercaChat**" while generating the pdf. Hence you get a blank pdf. You can simply generate without the specialElementHandlers:

```
doc.fromHTML($("#ricercaChat").html(), 15, 15);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (create a image from the html) instead:

```
// Javascript
function pdf() {
     var canvas = document.getElementById('ricercaChat');
     // save canvas image as data url (png format by default)
     var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

     var imgData = dataURL;

     var doc = new jsPDF();
     doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40);

     doc.save('role.pdf');
}
```

Comment: I don't take the div 'ricercaChat' with document.getElementById . It is inside a frame, so I take it with the name of the frame starting from the document element.
document.centro.contentCentro.ricercaChat

Comment: You can take whatever element you want. jsPDF will generate an image of what component you will choose. :)

Comment: toDataUrl is not a function.

Comment: anyway, i don't need an image, it is a log of a chat, so I need an html( or, at least, a plain text ) .. :)